# determine if the relation $xy \geq 1$ is an equivalence relation for $x,y \in R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, relations, equivalence-relations

I am having trouble with this one

To me its clear that $xy=yx\geq 1$ symmetric by the associative property.

To me its also clear that $xy = xy$ therefore the relation is reflexive.

we have $xy \geq 1$ and $1\geq\frac{1}{xy}$ so $xy \geq \frac{1}{xy}$ and is thus transitive

Did I correctly show that the relation is both symmetrical and reflexive? Is it not transitive?

Comment: Can you tell us what the equivalence relation is? Also, if $xy \geq 1$ then $\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{xy} \leq 1$.

Comment: $2\times 10≥1$ and $10\times \frac 13>1$ but $2\times \frac 13<1$.

Comment: Note:  to show relexivity you need to show that $xx≥1$ for all $x$ in your undisclosed set.

Comment: The relation is $xy\geq 1$

Comment: How do I show $xx\geq 1$

Comment: Okay @riley17 that makes sense. I can then show the transitive property?

Comment: Elements of absolute value less than $1$, like $1/2$ are not related to themselves. Therefore, the relation is not reflexive.

Comment: $xy\geq 1$ is not the definition of a relation. You need to properly define your relation and which set are you working in.

Comment: because then I get $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2} \neq \frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: @K.Gibson Because $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$ is not $\geq 1$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy that is very clear. I didn't consider all the possibilities in $R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For transitivity to hold we need $(xy\ge 1\land yz\ge 1)\implies (xz\ge 1)$ for all $x,y,z.$ But it's false when $x=z=1/2$ and $y=2.$